# ¿Cómo hago averiguar la moda en una lista de números de tipo bimodal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

resulta que tengo el siguiente código que averigua la moda de un grupo de datos,sin embargo solo funciona cuando existe únicamente una moda. ¿Me podrían ayudar a hacer una que funcione para listas bimodales,por favor? Realmente no tengo idea de como hacerlo, agradeceria además una explicación concisa de la respuesta.

```
dct={1:2,2:3,3:3,4:1}
print(max(dct,key=dct.get))
```

En este código la idea sería que el output fuese 2  y 3 ya que son las keys con mayor valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opcion sencilla es obtener el máximo de los valores y despues filtrar los elementos del diccionario:

```
dct = {1:2, 2:3, 3:3, 4:1}
m = max(dct.values())
moda = [key for key, value in dct.items() if value == m]
print(moda)
```

Salida:

```
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Por qué en la solución de @eyllanesc se pone la moda como una lista?

Comment: @Felka98 no te entiendo, explicate mejor

Comment: Lo siento,me refiero a por qué definiste la variable "moda" y pusiste los corchetes de lista, no entiendo porque debe ser una lista y por que el código no sirve sin los corchetes?

Comment: @Felka98 Eso se llama *list compression*, te permite reducir el numero de lineas haciendo mas elegante una solucion, y como lo dice el nombre, retorna una lista por ello es necesario los corchetes, es parte de la sintaxis de python.

Comment: @Felka98 ¿cual es el problema o incoveniente que tienes con mi solución?

Comment: Tu solución en realidad me parece mejor que todas las anteriores, no tiene ningún problema, era solo que no entendía la línea que hacia una list comprehension pero ahora sí, gracias por la explicación.

Comment: @Felka98 Cuando una respuesta es correcta se acostumbra aceptarla, si no sabes como hacerlo revisa el [tour], esa es la mejor forma de agradecer. :D

Comment: Ok perfecto, no sabía eso de aceptar respuestas

Answer (score 0):

No tengo muchos conocimientos en python por lo que no sabría darte una solución elegante pero ¿Qué tal si vas a lo simple y vas guardando las modas en una lista?
El código sería algo así:

```
dict = {1: 2, 2:3, 3:3, 4:1}

maximo, modas = float("-inf"), []

for clave, valor in dict.items():
    if valor > maximo:
        maximo = valor
        modas = [clave]
    elif valor == maximo:
        modas.append(clave)

print('Los valores modales son:', *modas, sep='\n')
```

Cada que se encuentra un valor que aparece más veces que los anterios, dicho valor y su número de repeticiones se guardan. Cuando se encuentran valores con las mismas repeticiones estos se van añadiendo a la lista de modas.

Answer (score 0):

Si las dos modas tienen exactamente el mismo número de repeticiones, las soluciones dadas en otras respuestas te valen. Pero si tienes una distribución en la que un valor se repite 100 veces, otro se repite 99 y el resto apenas 10 veces ¿considerarías esta distribución bimodal? Estrictamente la moda es la que se repite 100 veces, pero podría resultarte interesante conocer también que hay otra "casi moda" que aparece 99 veces.

Para casos así, lo más sencillo sería ordenar la distribución de forma decreciente por el número de repeticiones de cada elemento, y después seleccionar los 2 primeros.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

datos = {1:8, 2:100, 3:9, 4:99, 5:10}
sorted((e for e in datos.items()), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:2]
```

Salida

```
[(2, 100), (4, 99)]
```

### Actualización

El código anterior presupone que son dos las modas. Otro código más genérico para un caso multimodal podría ser el siguiente, en el cual puedes especificar la distancia máxima que toleras entre dos modas (en cuanto al número de repeticiones de cada una):

from operator import itemgetter

```
datos = {1:8, 2:100, 3:9, 4:99, 5:10, 6:98, 7:97 }
ordenado = sorted((e for e in datos.items()), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
result = []
cuenta_anterior = ordenado[0][1]  # El máximo de repeticiones
for valor, cuenta in ordenado:
  if cuenta_anterior - cuenta > 2:  # Distancia máxima permitida: 2
    break
  result.append((valor, cuenta))
  anterior = cuenta
```

Resultado:

```
[(2, 100), (4, 99), (6, 98)]
```